# Evaluating $\int_\mathbb R \frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2+1} dy - \int_\mathbb R \frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2+4} dy$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

$$\int_\mathbb R \frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2+1} dy - \int_\mathbb R \frac{e^{ixy}}{y^2+4} dy$$

I am wondering if it is feasible by hand or if my examinator does not want that I calculate it explicitly

Comment: You should try applying the residue theorem to a specific contour in the complex plane, then show that integral in the complex plane limits to the integral that you want.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating with respect to $x$?

Comment: A little more specific than cmk: try a contour consisting of the interval $[-R,R]$, and the upper half-circle of radius $R$. Find an upper bound for the integral along the half circle, and show that it goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a>0$ be a fixed real parameter, we would like to compute the integral
$$
g(x,a):=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ixy}\frac 1{y^2+a^2}\; dy
\ .
$$
First of all, we will get rid of $a$. For this we substitute $y=at$, so formally $dy=a\; dt$, and we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
g(x,a)
&=
\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-i\;xy}\frac 1{y^2+a^2}\; dy
\\
&=
\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ia\; xt}\frac 1{a^2(t^2+1^2)}\; a\; dt
\\
&=\frac 1a\; g(ax, 1)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So we can and do assume $a=1$, show for 
$$
g(x):=g(x,1)
=
\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ixy}\frac 1{y^2+1}\; dy
\text{ the formula }
g(x)=\pi e^{-|x|}
\ , 
$$
which implies $g(x,a) = \frac 1a g(ax,1)=
\frac\pi ae^{-a|x|}$ .

---

Now let us simply denote by $g(x)$ the function
$$
g(x) := \int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ixy}\frac 1{y^2+1}\; dy
\ .
$$
and show its claimed formula. There are two solutions below, both inspired from the hints of **cmk**, **Allawonder** and **Paul Sinclair** in the comments.

---

**(1)** The solution in the spirit of the complex analysis:

... it is the simplest, if the mechanism is understood.

Note that the substitution $y = -t$ shows $g(x) = g(-x)$. (Or expand $e^{ixy}=\cos(xy)+i\sin (xy)$ as a sum of two functions in $y$ with parameter $x$, the first one is even in $y$, the second one odd. Split the integral now correspondingly. The second integral vanishes, since $1/(y^2+1)$ is even. The first integral is invariated now w.r.t. the substitution $x\to -x$.)

After typing, i found the same argument as an example on the wiki page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#An_integral_along_the_real_axis

There are some small differences, so i let my text still here...

We may and do assume now $\color{red}{x\le 0}$, we fix it, and compute the integral of the analytic function $y \to e^{-ixy}/(y^2+1)$ on the following closed contour:

- start in $-R$ and go linearly to $R$ on the segment / interval $[-R,R]$, this converges to the integral $g(x)$ for $R\to\infty$, and
- from $R=Re^{i\cdot 0}$ go to $-R=Re^{i\cdot \pi}$ on the semicircle in the upper half plane parametrized by $t\to Re^{i\cdot t}$. On this contour, the function to be integrate can be estimated, 
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  |g(Re^{it})|
  &=
  \left|
  \frac 
  {e^{-ixR(\cos t+i\sin t)}}
  {R^2(\cos 2t+i\sin 2t) + 1}
  \right|
  \\
  &=
  \frac 
  {|e^{-ixR\cos t}|\cdot |e^{+xR\sin t}|}
  {|R^2(\cos 2t+i\sin 2t) + 1|}
  \\
  &=
  \frac 
  {|e^{+xR\sin t}|}
  {|R^2(\cos 2t+i\sin 2t)+1|}
  \\
  &\le
  \frac 
  1
  {|R^2(\cos 2t+i\sin 2t)+1|}
  \qquad\text{ essentially using }x\le0
  \\
  &\le
  \frac 1
  {|R^2(\cos 2t+i\sin 2t)|-|1|}
  =\frac 1{R^2-1}\ ,
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  and the corresponding integral on the contour is $\le $ than the length of the contour, the half circle, so $\pi R$, times the above estimation for the integrand. This contribution goes thus to $0$ (as is the case for $\pi R/(R^2-1)$) for $R\to\infty$. We get then applying the Residue Theorem:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  g(x) 
  &= 
  \int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ixy}\frac 1{y^2+1}\; dy
  \\
  &=\lim_{R\to\infty}
  \int_{-R}^{+R}e^{-ixy}\frac 1{y^2+1}\; dy
  \\
  &=\lim_{R\to\infty}
  \int_{\text{Contour}(R)}e^{-ixy}\frac 1{y^2+1}\; dy
  \\
  &=\lim_{R\to\infty}
  2\pi i\sum_{\text{Pole}=i}
  \operatorname{Residue}_{y=\text{Pole}}e^{-ixy}\frac 1{y^2+1}
  \\
  &=
  2\pi i\cdot
  \operatorname{Residue}_{y=i}e^{-ixy}\frac 1{(y-i)(y+i)}
  \\
  &=
  2\pi i\cdot
  \operatorname{Value}_{y=i}e^{-ixy}\frac 1{y+i}
  \\
  &=
  2\pi i\cdot\frac{e^x}{2i}=\pi e^x=\pi e^{-|x|}\ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  This finishes the first proof.

---

**(2)** The solution in the spirit of the Fourier Transform:

---

The general formula for the Fourier transformation $F$ of a function $f$ (in a good class of functions),
is
$$
F(x) =\hat f(x) :=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-ixy}\; f(y)\; dy\ ,
$$
and it is a property of the Fourier transform, that we can recover
$f$ from $F$ in a similar manner:
$$
f(y) =\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}e^{+ixy}\; F(x)\; dx\ .
$$
Now note that most tables of pairs of Fourier transforms also contain the function from the OP. (Tables usually come without proof.)
Maybe this is the reason for the exam question and the expectation to have an immediate answer.

For instance:

https://www.math.arizona.edu/~kglasner/math422/fouriertransform.pdf

To have here a kind of a proof, we use the given result, assume thus that the transformation of a function $f(y)$ is $F(x) = e^{-|x|}$, and we want to recover $f$. Using the formula for the inverse Fourier transfrom,
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(y) 
&=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}e^{+ixy}\; F(x)\; dx
\\
&=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}e^{+ixy}\; e^{-|x|}\; dx
\\
&=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_0^\infty (e^{+ixy}+e^{-ixy})\; e^{-x}\; dx
\\
&=\frac 1{2\pi}\left[ 
\ 
\frac 1{-(1+iy)}e^{-x(1+iy)}
+
\frac 1{-(1-iy)}e^{-x(1-iy)}
\
\right]_0^\infty
\\
&=\frac 1{2\pi}\left[ 
\ 
\frac 1{1+iy}
+
\frac 1{1-iy}
\
\right]
\\
&=\frac 1\pi\cdot\frac 1{1+y^2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now multiply with $\pi$ to get the needed pair.

Note: Solutions that use differential equations are not straightforward without tricks. For instance, let $D$ be the differential operator $D=i\partial_x$. Then the wanted solution $F(x) = e^{-|x|}$ satisfies on $\Bbb R\color{red}{-\{0\}}$ a differential equation, we just compute $(D^2+1)F(x)$, it corresponds to $(y^2+1)f(y)$, and we cannot avoid in a simple manner the Dirac in zero. (Except for the case we know what we are doing well. We may for instance multiply for this with $x$ or a higher power, in order to keep things simple, no distribution, no testing functions,
this is enought to get rid of the singularity in zero, use then partial integration w.r.t $y$ on the side with the integral...)

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer !